# Schema Validation error - The attribute {type} is referenced, but has not been declared

Tags: xsd

The SVG schema in question references the XLink schema which declares the xlink:type attribute, but getting error that the type has not been declared in XLink Schema.

svg.xsd

```
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:type" default="simple"/>
```

xlink.xsd

```
<xs:attribute name="type">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="simple"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Comment: Have you imported the xlink.xsd to the svg.xsd file?

Comment: Yes, it is imported in svg.xsd file.

Comment: <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="xlink.xsd"/>

Comment: xlink declarations in svg.xsd

Comment: <xs:attributeGroup name="SVG.XLink.attrib">
        <!--xs:attribute ref="xlink:type" default="simple"/-->
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:href"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:role"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:arcrole"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:title"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:show"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:actuate"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>

Comment: <xs:attributeGroup name="SVG.XLinkRequired.attrib">
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:type" default="simple"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:href" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:role"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:arcrole"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:title"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:show"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:actuate"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>

Comment: <xs:attributeGroup name="SVG.XLinkEmbed.attrib">
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:type" default="simple"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:href" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:role"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:arcrole"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xlink:title"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:show1"/>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:actuate"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>

Answer (score 0):

This is because the oxygen editor uses the default xlink.xsd from oxygen framework location and not from source schema location.